Any downside to getting separate health insurance for a child?
My wife and I have one child, and we are purchasing ACA marketplace insurance. I used to always purchase a “family” plan that covers all 3 of us. But I just realized it is cheaper to actually get a “couple” plan and a separate “child” plan, saving as much as $300 per month. Does this make sense or am I missing something? Are family plans worth it only for 2+ children?


Are family plans worth it only for 2+ children?

Nobody can say whether it's worth it without seeing the future. However, the "2+" is not a factor any family plan has different payouts depending on what happens, and therefore different risk profiles and costs.
For simplicity, ignore the deductible and assume there's an out-of-pocket max at $4000 individually. This means a family plan has a OOP max at $8000. You have 2 adults and 1 kid.
Healthy family. Adults use $500 each and the child uses $750. Insurance pays 0.

Separately insured: $1750 out of pocket
Family plan: $1750
Child separate from couple: $1750

One adult gets in a catastrophic situation that hits the OOP max. Other spending is the same.

Separately insured: $4000 + $500 + $750 = $5,250 OOP
Family plan: $8,000
Child separate from adults: $8000 + $750 = $8,750

Everybody gets in a catastrophic situation, like they're traveling in the same car and it crashes.

Separately insured: $4000 * 3 = $12,000
Family plan: $8,000
Child separate from adults: $8000 + $4000 = $12,000

In two cases here, your out-of-pocket contribution is higher when the child is separate. This is why your overall premiums are less.
A major consideration why family coverage has deductibles/OOP max twice that of individual coverage is with 2 adults, income and affordability is, presumably, twice that of an individual. When you add children, you don't add income

I believe in a car crash scenario the auto insurance would pay for the care. One time I got a wrist injury and my health insurance made me sign a form certifying that it was not related to an auto accident.

@V00 Not always. If somebody else was at fault, their third-party liability would pay first. (Keep in mind, mandatory limits can be low as $15k) If you were at fault, including single-vehicle accidents, any auto medical coverage pays first (limited to $5k in my state) then falls over to medical insurance. If you were in a no-fault state, your own mandatory auto medical coverage would pay first. It's normally best to claim through your own health insurance first, the question they ask about auto/workers comp is to see if they can make a subrogated claim (sue) to get the money they pay back.

Some states have both no-fault insurance and medical insurance as the primary payer. You need catastrophic loss coverage from your car insurance to cover whatever medical doesn't. Michigan switched to this kind of coverage in 2020.

I have not looked at this, but I do see this is possible. Some people do this due to medicare or medicaid rules and costs.
The first thought is: how does the deductible work? Could you end up paying more because one policy hits the deductible but the other just misses?
The same question for maximum out of pocket.
How does this impact any subsidies?
While it isn't unusual to have separate doctors for parents and children: having separate ones for dentists and pharmacies is. Unless they are the same insurance company this could happen.
The amount you quote, $300 a month, is significant.  But if it was lower, lets say $50 a month, would the extra bureaucracy of separate logins, and rules make it worth it?

Yes, seems like the main downside is not sharing the family deductible / out of pocket maximum. However, two family members would both need to max out their deductible for it to even be a factor - unlikely, since we're all in good health and it's a HDHP. The doctor selection isn't an issue since it's the same insurer/network. But this works only for a family with one child. With two children and especially three or more, the family plan is a better deal.

I don't know what alternatives to ACA you're considering but for my family my spouse and I are independently insured through our employers but I use an HDCP with HSA while she uses an HMO.
This allows me to maximally fund my "family HSA" for my child and I who generally have no annual health expenses while my spouse has above-average expenses.
So if you are thinking about an HSA as a retirement vehicle, like me, then it's an independent consideration.
